# Select from a select result using lag

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

This is the scenario given

```
SELECT * 
FROM   arcade_machine_history_movement 
WHERE  code_machine = 23502 
ORDER  BY date_movement ASC; 


CODE_MACHINE TYPE          date_movement   CURRENT_COMPANY 
23502        T             01/01/2015      SPAIN GAMES
23502        T             01/03/2016      SPAIN GAMES
23502        T             01/01/2016      SPAIN GAMES
23502        S             01/01/2019      FUN GAMES
23502        T             11/01/2019      FUN GAMES
23502        S             11/03/2019      POKER STAR
```

The table arcade_machine_history_movement represents all the history movements of the slots machines. The 'S' it means a sale from a company from another.

I want to get the sales movements of each slot machine and get the current company (buyer), and the previous company (the one who sells the machine)

This is what I have done

```
SELECT code_machine, 
   type_m, 
   current_company, 
   Lag (current_company) 
     OVER ( 
       ORDER BY date_movement ASC) AS previous_company 
       FROM   arcade_machine_history_movement 
       WHERE  code_machine = 23502;
```

With the lag i get the previous company of each row.

So this is the result.

```
code_machine type_m  date_movement current_company previous_company
23502        T  01/01/2015   SPAIN GAMES     
23502        T  01/03/2016   SPAIN GAMES     SPAIN GAMES
23502        T  01/01/2016   SPAIN GAMES     SPAIN GAMES 
23502        S  01/01/2019   FUN GAMES       SPAIN GAMES    
23502        T  11/01/2019   FUN GAMES       SPAIN GAMES
23502        S    11/03/2019     POKER GAMES     FUN GAMES
```

So now I want to create another select from that previous select, to get only the 'S' movements, but I don't know to do it correctly.

```
code_machine type_m    date_movement   current_company      previous_company
23502        S        11/03/2019      FUN GAMES           SPAIN GAMES
23502        S        11/03/2019      POKER GAMES         FUN GAMES
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT   code_machine, 
     type_m, 
     date_movement, 
     current_company, 
     previous_company 
FROM     (code_machine,type_m,date_movement, current_company, lag 
(current_company) OVER (ORDER BY date_movement ASC) AS empresa_anterior 
FROM arcade_machine_history_movement WHERE code_machine 23502)
WHERE    type_m ='S';
```

I run this query but it doesn't finish and it's thinking all the time.

I use Oracle SQL developer

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT amhm.*
FROM (SELECT amhm.*, 
             Lag(current_company) OVER (PARTITION BY code_machine ORDER BY date_movement ASC) AS previous_company 
      FROM arcade_machine_history_movement amhm
      WHERE code_machine = 23502
     ) amhm
WHERE type = 'S';
```

Comment: That works mate! Thanks. The table had more columns than the ones I put it on the post. There is any way to only get the columns I posted?

Comment: There is any way to only get the columns I posted?  code_machine type_m    date_movement   current_company      previous_company

Comment: @user3671361 . . . Just select the columns you want in the outer query.  The particular columns being selected don't affect the important part of the logic, so I just shortened the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I would do a  JOIN with that subquery how it would be the syntaxis?

Comment: @user3671361 . . . Just as you would with any other query.  You can turn this into a subquery or CTE and write a `join`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the first request by adding the "AND" and the second condition:

```
SELECT code_machine, 
   type_m, 
   current_company, 
   Lag (current_company) 
     OVER ( 
       ORDER BY date_movement ASC) AS previous_company 
       FROM   arcade_machine_history_movement 
       WHERE  code_machine = 23502 AND type_m = 'S';
```

Comment: the result of using `lag` here would not be from the previous row because you are filtering only for type_m='S' rows.

Comment: This returns the previous_company  empty, becuse you are filtering only the 'S' rows. For that, I have to use a select form the select I obtain.